# AIX putty terminal color using tput

Tags: unix, terminal, putty, aix, xterm

I am trying to set colors using **tput setb or setab** function but I am unable to get colors. On the positive side tput bold , underline like functions are working. I am unable to find any reasons for setb function issue.

```
print $(tput bold)"Text is bold"$(tput sgr0)
```

[image: print $(tput bold)"Text is bold"$(tput sgr0)]

Could you please help me to use the **tput set** function to create colors?

I am using putty 0.65 release, TERM=xterm-256color and AIX version = 7.1

I have tried using a different method from google as below. **But I would like to use tput set for easy purpose rather than hard coding color values.**  Kindly help me to understand.

```
__GREEN='\033[0;32m'
print  ${__GREEN}$(tput bold)"Green color Bold" $(tput sgr0)
```

[image: print ${__GREEN}$(tput bold)"Green color Bold" $(tput sgr0)]

Comment: Are you just experimenting, or actually want to change colors? If the latter, use escape sequences `ESC [ 30+fgcolorno m` and ESC [ 40+bgcolorno m` More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined below and it worked. Thanks!

```
 __GREEN='\033[0;32m'
 __NC='\033[0m' # No Color

 print -n ${__GREEN}$(tput bold)
 banner  DEVELOPER
 print -n $(tput sgr0)${__NC}
```

I am using AIX Lpar and putty

Answer (score 0):

The **`setb`** (and **`setf`**) capabilities are not provided in the terminal description because they're used for non-ANSI colors.  Use **`setab`** (and **`setaf`**).

> - To change the current foreground or  background  color  on  a  Tektronix-type  terminal,  use  setaf  (set ANSI foreground) and setab
>     (set ANSI background) or setf (set foreground) and setb (set  background).   These  take  one  parameter, the color number.  The SVr4
>     documentation describes only setaf/setab; the XPG4 draft says  that
>     *"If  the  terminal supports ANSI escape sequences to set background
>     and foreground, they should be coded as **setaf**  and  **setab**,  respectively.*

ncurses' [terminfo manpage](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Color-Handling) says this:

> - If  the  terminal supports other escape sequences to set background
>     and foreground, they should be coded  as  setf  and  setb,  respectively.   The  vidputs  and the refresh(3x) functions use the setaf
>     and setab capabilities if they are defined.

Colors are numbered, either way:

```
for n in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7;do tput setab $n;echo background $n;done; tput sgr0
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried setaf and setab, and it's not working. I am using putty. Will it work there?